# ftp_get doesn't work with accented characters

Tags: php, unicode, ftp

I'm using ftp_get to get files from ftp servers in my php script it works except when filename contains accented characters.
Exemple: `ftp_get($conn_id,"tmpfile", "matériel.xlsx")`

I tried :

```
ftp_get($conn_id,"tmpfile", urlencode("matériel.xlsx"))
ftp_get($conn_id,"tmpfile", utf8_encode("matériel.xlsx"))
ftp_get($conn_id,"tmpfile", utf8_decode("matériel.xlsx"))
```

Nothing works

Comment: Have you tried ftp_raw('OPTS UTF8 ON') ?